# Why doesn't \samepage set \predisplaypenalty (to \@M or any other value)?

Tags: page-breaking, tex-core, samepage

latex.ltx defines a no–page-break command as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\samepage{\interlinepenalty\@M
   \postdisplaypenalty\@M
   \interdisplaylinepenalty\@M
   \@beginparpenalty\@M
   \@endparpenalty\@M
   \@itempenalty\@M
   \@secpenalty\@M
   \interfootnotelinepenalty\@M}
```

Where has the TeX's `\predisplaypenalty` gone? *The TeXbook* defines it as the penalty for page break just before a display. Shouldn't `\predisplaypenalty\@M` also be there?  Should anything else be added to the definition of `\samepage`, or, perhaps, should any line be removed from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX sets  `\predisplaypenalty` to 10000 and no standard setting changes that so there is no need for `\samepage` to reset it.

Comment: Thx! So if, for whatever reason, the classes or packages I use set `\predisplaypenalty` to 0 (e.g., svmono.cls does this), is it a good idea to add `\predisplaypenalty\@M` to samepage, say, with a patch command? Or does `\predisplaypenalty` apply really only to the math-opening `$$` (and not to, say, `\[` or `\begin{gather*}`)?

Comment: no it applies to them all.so yes you could change `\samepage` in that case @AlMa0

Comment: Thanks! I have a choice between the following: `\let\oldsamepage\samepage\makeatletter\def\samepage{\oldsamepage\predisplaypenalty\@M}\makeatother`, `\makeatletter\g@addto@macro\samepage{\predisplaypenalty\@M}\makeatother`, `\makeatletter\pretocmd{\samepage}{\predisplaypenalty\@M}{}{\typeout{\verb!\samepage! could not be redefined}}\makeatother`, and `\makeatletter\apptocmd{\samepage}{\predisplaypenalty\@M}{}{\typeout{\verb!\samepage! could not be redefined}}\makeatother`. Any idea which one to take? Or should I patch the environment `samepage` instead of the command `samepage` somehow?

Comment: Or `\makeatletter\patchcmd\samepage{\predisplaypenalty\@M}{}\makeatother` or `\makeatletter\patchcmd\samepage{}{\predisplaypenalty\@M}\makeatother`?  There are so many (working or not working) patch commands that I'm confused which one is the right one for the given circumstances.

Comment: I'd just use the code you put on your question with one line added

Comment: One might argue that the kernel should add `\predisplaypenalty\@M`, since classes can (and apparently do) change the value. Why does `svmono` sets it to 0? I can see no reason, but …

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So a new `\DeclareRobustCommand\samepage{…}` would overwrite the old one?

Comment: @egreg I don't know the thoughts of the author of svmono, but I think it's trivial. Doesn't the value 0 allow a block formula `\[…\]` to appear on the very top of a page?

Comment: @AlMa0 Yes, which should be considered bad typography

Comment: @egreg Why? After all, all page breaks are bad in the sense that they disturb the read flow *in general*. A priori, it's NOT worse to switch from a paragraph on the bottom of one page to a formula than to another paragraph on the top of next page. There's nothing bad about formulas starting a page *per se*.

Comment: @AlMa0 Knuth says in the texbook "Plain TeX sets `\predisplaypenalty=1000`, because fine printers traditionally shun displayed formulas at the very top of a page." so some people would disagree with "nothing bad". Even if you reduce it from 10000 to allow it when needed, going to 0 and not discouraging it at all is surprising

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This statement of Knuth simply implies that putting a formula at the top of a page is or was *untraditional* (in Knuth's view) and not *bad*. By the way, is there a typo in your comment, and one 0 is missing? I read “Plain TeX sets `\predisplaypenalty=10000`, because […]” in *The TeXbook*.

Comment: @AlMa0 sorry lost a 0 converting to markdown

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thx. Probably, the traditional publishers were thinking of usages where the text before a block formula introduces the formula, such as `Now let's consider the function\[f \quad=\quad  \uplambda n.\ \mathrm{if}\ \mathrm{even}(n)\ \mathrm{then}\ n/2\ \mathrm{else}\ 3n+1\ .\]` Here, a page break is a *tiny bit* unfortunate, but still better than within a text paragraph.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In usages such as `Now let's consider the following functions:\begin{gather*}f = …\\g = …\\h = …\end{gather*}`, with a vertically large block of formulas, it might be even better to introduce a page break before (or after) the block than within it or within a text paragraph.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So welcoming or inhibiting a page break before a formula block is a context-sensitive decision.

Answer (score 2):

Even though normally the value is not changed from 10000 I agree with @egreg that we could set it in `\samepage` in the kernel just to be on the safe side. For now the simplest fix might be

```
\AddToHook{cmd/samepage/after}{\predisplaypenalty10000\relax}
```

Comment: Thx! Can we issue this in the preamble of a user document? Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680215. If you say you will definitely change the kernel, then, well, no action from me as a user is needed.

Comment: yes, that's my point. As written you don't need to load an extra package and you don't need \makeatletter. If we add it directly in the kernel at some point, the setting doesn't hurt except that it would then be unnecessary setting  \predisplaypenalty again.

Comment: Just added it to the development format so it will become part of LaTeX in June

Comment: Your change is not (yet) part of texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/latex.ltx or texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx in the current TeX Live 2023 as of now. Is in June your improvement supposed to propagate to texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/latex.ltx or already to texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?

Comment: @AlMa0 patience ... June is not there. The next dev format which we will distribute this week will have it and and the June release (probably slightly delayed this time) will have it too.