# How to patch samepage for svmono?

Tags: patching, samepage

Continuing [Why doesn't \samepage set \predisplaypenalty (to \@M or any other value)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680211) , let's say we wish to patch LaTeX's

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\samepage{\interlinepenalty\@M
   \postdisplaypenalty\@M
   \interdisplaylinepenalty\@M
   \@beginparpenalty\@M
   \@endparpenalty\@M
   \@itempenalty\@M
   \@secpenalty\@M
   \interfootnotelinepenalty\@M}
```

by means of adding `\predisplaypenalty\@M` somewhere (e.g., because your classes or packages (say, svmono.cls) set `\predisplaypenalty` to a value less than `\@M`.)
We do not plan to use `\samepage` directly but rather `\begin{samepage}…\end{samepage}`
Which way to go?

My attempts have failed so far. Here's one example of failure:

```
\documentclass{svmono}% version 5.10 (08-Sep-21); cf. http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation#toc-49268 or http://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs
% at this spot we wish to redefine the samepage environment, but this one doesn't work:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\samepage}{\interfootnotelinepenalty\@M}{\interfootnotelinepenalty\@M\predisplaypenalty\@M}{}{\typeout{samepage could not be redefined}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{samepage}
  \strut\vskip120ex
  \begin{remark}[A remark name]\label[remark]{label}
    \[
      \text{a formula}
    \]
    \begin{center}%
      Table caption\\%%% probably better \nopagebreak\\ instead of \\, but anyway, samepage should better do all the job itself.
      \hbox to \hsize{\hfill
        \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}
          \hline
          Some table\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \hfill\llap{$\square$}}%
    \end{center}%
  \end{remark}%
\end{samepage}
\end{document}
```

yields

> samepage could not be redefined

in the log and a page break in the remark:

[image: output]

How to properly™ extend or redefine the `samepage` environment such that we don't get a page break inside the remark?

Answer (score 0):

`etoolbox` cannot patch commands defined using `\DeclareRobustCommand`. You can use package `xpatch` to append code to a robust command with `\xapptocmd`. Here you can see, that the patch is used:

```
\documentclass{svmono}% version 5.10 (08-Sep-21); cf. http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation#toc-49268 or http://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs
% at this spot we wish to redefine the samepage environment, but this one doesn't work:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\samepage}{\predisplaypenalty\@M}{}{\PatchFailure}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{samepage}
  \strut\vskip120ex
  \begin{remark}[A remark name]\label[remark]{label}
    \verb|\predisplaypenalty| is \the\predisplaypenalty
    \[
      \text{a formula}
    \]
    \begin{center}%
      A table\\%%% probably better \nopagebreak\\ instead of \\, but anyway, samepage should better do all the job itself.
      \hbox to \hsize{\hfill
        \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}
          \hline
          Some table\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \hfill\llap{$\square$}}%
    \end{center}%
  \end{remark}%
\end{samepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: \predisplaypenatly is 10000]

But if you have a look at the whole thing, you can also see, that this does not prevent the page break after the `remark` head:

[image: unwanted page break after remark head]

And even, if you mode the `\begin{samepage}` *after* `\strut\vskip120ex` you would get the same result

So the root of your problem is not the `\predisplaypentalty`. If you really don't want a page break inside a `remark`, I would suggest to use a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{svmono}% version 5.10 (08-Sep-21); cf. http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation#toc-49268 or http://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs
% at this spot we wish to redefine the samepage environment, but this one doesn't work:
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,cleveref}
\begin{document}
  \strut\vskip120ex
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{remark}[A remark name]\label[remark]{label}
    \[
      \text{a formula}
    \]
    \begin{center}%
      A table\\%%% probably better \nopagebreak\\ instead of \\, but anyway, samepage should better do all the job itself.
      \hbox to \hsize{\hfill
        \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}
          \hline
          Some table\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \hfill\llap{$\square$}}%
    \end{center}%
  \end{remark}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

If you only not want a page break at the beginning of the `remark`, use package `needspace`.

Comment: Thx! Any idea why we still get a page break inside the samepage environment after your change?

Comment: @AlMa0 `samepage` is more a kind of: “prevent implicit page breaks, if possible” and not “prevent all kind of page breaks”, because it does not prevent explicitly allowed page breaks. So using `samepage` to prevent all kind of page breaks is simply wrong. You have to inspect the definition of `remark` in `svmono` to find out, why and where it allows page breaks, e.g., because of using `\item` inside a `trivlist` or adding vertical space. In other words: You can use a knife to remove screws, but will not always succeed. The proper screwdriver is the better tool.

Comment: I see. The class svmono.cls defines `remark` via `\spn@wtheorem`, which I mostly don't understand :-(.